# how can I set the interval to 10 ms and still matplotlib can animated?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm setting up a gateway that takes readings from two stations through TCP connection every 10 ms. the gateway should display these readings for each station using matplotlib and compute the average of these reading and display it as well.

the animated plots were working fine when I tested it for the three plots with setting the interval = 1000. But when I set the interval = 10 no subplots are shown. and when I set it to 500, at the start it works but after the stations connect to the gateway the animation freezes

I need the interval to be 10 ms because of the requirement

this is for station 1

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import socket
from random import randint
#import time

HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = 4444        # The port used by the server
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))  # connecting to local server
    while True:
        data = randint(1, 10)
        data = str(data)  # user input
        s.send(data.encode('ascii'))  # encoding the user input then sending to server
        data = s.recv(1024)
        data = data.decode('ascii')
```

this is for  station 2

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket
from random import randint
#import time

HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = 5555        # The port used by the server
#time.sleep(.00000001)
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))  # connecting to local server
    while True:
        data = randint(1, 10)
        data = str(data)  # user input
        s.send(data.encode('ascii'))  # encoding the user input then sending to server
        data = s.recv(1024)
        data = data.decode('ascii')
        #print (data)
```

and this is the gateway

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#
#
import _thread
import socket
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation


HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT1 = 4444  # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)
PORT2 = 5555
Station1Data = 0
Station2Data = 0
average = 0


def server1():
    s =  socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((HOST, PORT1))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            data = data.decode('ascii')
            conn.send(data.encode('ascii'))
            #print(data)
            global Station1Data
            Station1Data = int(data)


def server2():
    s =  socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((HOST, PORT2))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            data = data.decode('ascii')
            conn.send(data.encode('ascii'))
            global Station2Data
            Station2Data = int(data)


def average():
    global Station1Data, Station2Data, average
    while True:
        average = (Station1Data+Station2Data)/2







try:
    _thread.start_new_thread(server1, ())
    _thread.start_new_thread(server2, ())
    _thread.start_new_thread(average,())

except:
    print("Error: unable to start thread")

fig = plt.figure()
#plt.xlabel('time')
#plt.ylabel('Mw                Mw               Mw')
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(3,1,1)
x = 19
xs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]
ys = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(3,1,2)
x2 = 19
xs2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]
ys2 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(3,1,3)
x3=19
xs3 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]
ys3 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]


def animate(i):
    global x,xs,ys,Station1Data
    x = x+1
    xs.append(x)
    ys.append(Station1Data)
    xs = xs[-20:]
    ys = ys[-20:]
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.set_xticklabels([])
    ax1.plot(xs, ys,'b')
    ax1.set_title('Station1')


def animate2(i):
    global x2,xs2,ys2,Station2Data
    x2 = x2+1
    xs2.append(x2)
    ys2.append(Station2Data)
    xs2 = xs2[-20:]
    ys2 = ys2[-20:]
    ax2.clear()
    ax2.set_xticklabels([])
    ax2.plot(xs2, ys2,'r')
    ax2.set_title('Station2')


def animate3(i):
    global x3,xs3,ys3,average
    x3 = x3+1
    xs3.append(x3)
    ys3.append(average)
    xs3 = xs3[-20:]
    ys3 = ys3[-20:]
    ax3.clear()
    ax3.set_xticklabels([])
    ax3.plot(xs3, ys3,'g')
    ax3.set_title('average')


animation1 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=10)
animation12 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate2, interval=10)
animation13 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate3, interval=10)

plt.show()
```

thanks in advance for your help

sorry if this is messy

Comment: I can't say anything about the source of the error, but for sure you should use one single animation, not 3 of them.

Comment: I tried that now. I set the interval to 100 and it works but it is very slow. at least better.

Comment: There are a lot of questions about improving animation speed out there.

Comment: the problem is I was using three infinite while loops by different threads. and that was killing my ram on my device. also, the three animations were using a lot of the ram.